# Obtaining ChromeDrivers version number from Powershell via a Java script

Tags: java, powershell, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a small Java app that includes checking the ChromeDriver version for automation tests, but as ChromeDriver does not report the version number in the metadata and can only be retrieved in Powershell using 'chromedriver.exe --version', I'm attempting to send this as a command to Powershell but get the error - "The term 'chromedriver.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file........".

I assume that this because it is not a recognised Powershell command as 'Get-Command' or 'Get-Item' would be for obtaining the version number.

How does this need to be sent for it to report on the version number?

I have also tried used the BufferedOutputWriter and PrintWriter to send it just as text, but get the same issue.

Comment: Looks like `chromedriver.exe` is not in `PATH`. You need to specify full path to executable.

Comment: You shouldn't need PowerShell at all. Launch `chromedriver.exe` from Java directly, using its absolute path. Redirect stdout of `chromedriver.exe` using API provided by Java (I have never used it, but this is a common task that should be doable through Java API).